# как сделать переадрессацию htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Kак сделать переадрессацию с помощю htaccess с site.com/en/ на site.com?lang=en

Comment: `Redirect 301 /en/ http://site.com?lang=en`

Comment: это поидет для `site.com/en/some/other/path` и конец меняеться

Comment: я думал как-то с мод ревритом

Comment: а с `site.com/en/some/other/path` тоже на `site.com?lang=en` требуется? Например так: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /en/  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com?lang=en [R=301,L]`

Comment: с site.com/en/some/other/path,  на site.com/some/other/path?lang=en, просто удалить en, ru или другое укороченное название языка и присабачить его в конец в виде ?lang=en (вместо en нужный язык из ссылки)